# SQL GROUP BY column from related table

Tags: sql, select, group-by, db2

I have table T1

```
ID     RESOLVER   RESOLVEDBY
1      A          GROUP1
2      A          GROUP1
3      A          GROUP1
4      B          GROUP1
5      B          GROUP1
```

I have also table T2

```
GROUPID   GROUP      PERSON
1         GROUP1     A      
2         GROUP1     B
3         GROUP1     C
```

I made this SQL query which return how many records are resolved by each person

```
select resolver,count(*) from T1
where resolvedby='GROUP1'
group by resolver
```

and it returns correctly

```
A 3
B 2
```

However I would also like to retrieve this statistics for all persons which belong to that group so for user C I would like to have value 0.
So the final result should be

```
A 3
B 2
C 0
```

Comment: `right outer join`.

Comment: Your result doesn't match your data. You seem to join on `resolver=person` instead.

Comment: sorry I corrected and edited my statement how I return currently result. But still remains the question on which way to retrieve desired result

Comment: You have the group in both tables, because they make up the natural key (i.e. a persons name can occur multiple times, but only once per group), correct?

Comment: Yes once per group but person name can be presented multiple times if person is the member of another group also

Comment: GROUP is a bad column name by the way, because it's a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit:

You need to outer join your existing Select to the 2nd table:

```
select t2.person, coalesce(cnt, 0)
from T2
left join
 ( -- aggregate before join (usually more efficient)
   select resolver,count(*) as cnt
   from T1
   where resolvedby='GROUP1'
   group by resolver
 ) as T1
on T1.resolver=T2.person
where t2."GROUP"='GROUP1' -- adding double quotes as GROUP is usually a keyword
```

Comment: @Dejan: There's `GROUP1`
 data in your example data, too. After your new edit it's column `GROUP`

Comment: sorry I saw it my mistake...I corrected now that column in first table is RESOLVEDBY while in second table is the GROUP. Can you please double check your query now? Thanks and sorry

Comment: THANKS it worked only one thing I need that you have to change instead of T2.resolver=T1.person to be T1.resolver=T2.person correct?

Comment: And just a small question if I want to filter additionally T1 table I need to filter just the first WHERE clause correct?? I do not have to put anything additionally in second WHERE??? This is just a question for filtering additionally T1 table..everything else remains

Comment: @Dejan: You can add any additional WHERE-condition to T1, of course this might change the returned count.

Comment: thanks. but I am stuggling still. I marked your  answer just a question if for example I would like to filter additionally groups in which I am interested and RESOLVER people in which I am interested for example RESOLVEDBY should include GROUP1 and GROUP2 then I have to put those two conditions in both WHERE correct?

Comment: Additionally if I want to filter list of people for RESOLVER field then I need to add condition filter for example RESOLVER in ('A','B','C','D','E') just in the first clause correct?

Comment: @Dejan: Yes. If you add more conditions you might switch to Thorsten Kettner's Correlated Subquery. Which one is more efficient depends on the number of rows in your tables & rows returned.

Comment: OK so I will add conditions just in the first subquery. In case of Thorstan case I also need to put conditions just in the first subquery?

Comment: @Dejan: Just try it. You put conditions in that place where you need it to get the expected result.

Comment: Hi can you please help me with this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364018/sql-using-count-and-case-for-related-table-error-is-returned  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Outer join the counts to the person table. Use `COALESCE` to show 0 when there is no entry in T2.

```
select t2.person, t2.group, coalesce(counted.cnt, 0)
from t2
left join
(
  select resolver, resolvedby, count(*) as cnt
  from T1
  group by resolver, resolvedby
) counted on counted.resolver = t2.person and counted.resolvedby = t2.group
where t2.group = 'GROUP1';
```

You could also use a subquery in the select clause instead:

```
select 
  t2.person, 
  t2.group, 
  (select count(*) from t1 where t1.resolver = t2.person and t1.resolvedby = t2.group)
from t2
where t2.group = 'GROUP1';
```

Comment: thanks and just a small question if I want to filter additionally T1 table I need to filter just to put WHERE in the first where clause correct?? or I will have to put additionally condition in second WHERE??? This is just a question for filtering additionally T1 table..everything else remains

Comment: If you want to filter T1 records (e.g. only count those where a flag in the record is set) put the criteria in T1's where clause, i.e. in `where` right after `from t1`.

Comment: Hi Thorsten can you please also help me with this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364018/sql-using-count-and-case-for-related-table-error-is-returned  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer join to return all records from T2. The below query uses a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to return all rows from T2 (i.e. including a row for C) and gets the matching counts for each of them:

```
select T2.PERSON, count(T1.ID) from T1
right outer join T2 on T2.PERSON=T1.RESOLVER 
where T2.group ='GROUP1' -- If this was T1.group, we'd have to use COALESCE() to prevent dropping out rows in T2 that don't have a resolution in T1 
group by T2.PERSON
```

Above, we use a right outer join because we need all the rows from the table/expression to the **right** of the statement `right outer join`. If we had written the query's `FROM` clause with `T2` first, it would have been a left outer join like so: `...T2 left outer join T1...`

Comment: please take a look at my modified sql which I used. Unfortunately your query does not give me what I would like. Can you notice the error maybe?

Comment: @Dejan - I've updated the query in my answer with a `WHERE` clause. Do note that the column names in your example are mismatched :-) For example, your query has `where resolvedby='GROUP1'` but there is no `resolvedby` column in either T1 or T2.

Comment: sorry I saw it my mistake...I corrected now that column in first table is RESOLVEDBY while in second table is the GROUP. Can you please double check your query now? Thanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get expected output as per your requirement.

```
select person,count(resolver) from t2 left join t1 on t2.groups=t1.groups and t2.person = t1.resolver  group by person;

OUTPUT : 

mysql> select person,count(resolver) from t2 left join t1 on t2.person = t1.resolver  group by person;
+--------+-----------------+
| person | count(resolver) |
+--------+-----------------+
| A      |               4 |
| B      |               3 |
| C      |               0 |
+--------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```