# SQL using COUNT and CASE for related table - error is returned

Tags: sql, select, count, db2, case

I have table T1:

```
ID  GROUPINFO    STATUS
1   GROUP1       NEW
2   GROUP1       INPROG
3   GROUP2       INPROG
```

I  have table T2 also

```
T2ID    T1ID  STATUS
 1       1      NEW
 2       2      NEW
 3       2      VENDOR
 4       3      NEW
 5       3      VENDOR
```

I want to count by group how many of those records have the status NEW, and how many of those records were in the status VENDOR (information from T2 table)

This SQL works

```
SELECT T1.GROUPINFO,
count (case when T1.status='NEW' then 1 end) as New
FROM T1
GROUP BY T1.GROUPINFO
```

However when I try to add how many of those records were in the VENDOR status I am getting an error:

```
SELECT T1.GROUPINFO,
count (case when T1.status='NEW' then 1 end) as New,
count (case when T1.ID in (select T2.ID from T2 where T2.status='VENDOR') then 1 end) as Vendor
FROM T1
GROUP BY T1.GROUPINFO
```

I am getting an error:

Bad Plan; Unresolved QNC found

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how should I organize my SQL query so I could get this result for this example:

```
GROUPINFO   NEW   VENDOR
GROUP1       1     1
GROUP2       0     1
```

If ID exists multiple times in T2 it should only be counted 1 time because this is one record for which I want to check if it was in that status or not.

Update:
I also tried EXISTS:

```
SELECT T1.GROUPINFO,
count (case when T1.status='NEW' then 1 end) as New,
count (case when exists (select 1  from T2 where T2.ID=T1.ID and T2.status='VENDOR') then 1 end) as Vendor
FROM T1
GROUP BY T1.GROUPINFO
```

but again having an SQL error: regarding the ID column

Update:
I also tried EXISTS and JOIN:

```
SELECT T1.GROUPINFO,
count (case when T1.status='NEW' then 1 end) as New,
count (case when exists (select 1  from T2 where T2.ID=T1.ID and T2.status='VENDOR') then 1 end) as Vendor
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.GROUPINFO
```

but again having an SQL error: regarding the ID column

Comment: you can join them on id instead trying a nested query in a case statement. you might need a temporary table joining them first then you can get the desired result from that table

Comment: Can you please provide example? Since it seems it is not so simple, I tried even JOIN but it is very important that I must do group by based on GROUPINFO column and not on ID column

Comment: I updated what I have tried but again having an issue. Can you please help me if you have some kind of solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select T3.Groupinfo,
count (distinct(case when t3.status="NEW" then t3.ID end)) as new,
count (distinct(case when t3.status_1 ="VENDOR" then t3.id end)) as Vendor
from 
(select t1.groupinfo,t1.id,t1.status,t2.t2id as id1,t2.status as status_1 from
t1 join t2
on t1.id=t2.t1id
) as t3
group by t3.Groupinfo;
```

Something Similar to this might help you i guess.

Comment: may I ask you 2 questions? If VENDOR status for specific ID (for example ID 1) exists multiple times in T2 table will your COUNT count it multiple times or just once because that is the same ID record? I would like to have counted it only 1 can you please confirm this?. And second question if I want to filter additionally my TABLE T1 I am adding where clause just after the JOIN and ON clauses correct? I am not filtering it after the T3 clause correct?

Comment: it would count it twice since it is grouped by groupinfo and not id. you can add further conditions after on clause inside the sub query because that would be much more efficient.If you want to get single values you might have to remove duplicates with the combination of groupinfo,id and status_1

Comment: I updated my TABLE T2 please take a look. It has its own ID but tables T1 and T2 are connected through the T1 ID column.. You mentioned to group it by GROUPINFO, ID and STATUS1 but I all those have the same value I just want to COUNT it once

Comment: If I put DISTINCT after count I am having an error and sql query cannot be executed :(

Comment: what distinct values do you want? is it on id from T1 or T2Id from T2?

Comment: really sorry for all confusion. In T1 I have unique ID which may appear multiple times in T2 table on T1ID column. But if ID1 appears multiple times in T2 for same T1ID value and for the status VENDOR it should be counted only one, while T2 ID can have multiple values but this is not relevant since it is only important for me if for ID exists VENDOR status value in T2 table (it is not important how many times). Thank you in advance

Comment: also your query because of the JOIN creates me multiple results for ALL COUNTS which is not good and it makes incorrect result:(

Comment: I must count number of records in T1 table grouped by GROUPINFO column but in this way I am getting multiple results because of the JOIN

Comment: i have edited the answer from what i understood from your comment. Check whether this your desired output

Comment: I checked but error is returned for CONCAT function. I suppose this is because db2 CONCAT can concatenate only 2 columns while you are eputting multiple in it?

Comment: then you can remove the third column it is insignificant in the query

Comment: I am not sure how far from the result we are currently since we have two issues currently - one is that mutiple records are returned for all COUNT clauses because of the JOIN with T2 table and second issue is because I must count just once this ID from T1 which can appear multiple times in T2 table in T1ID column for status VENDOR

Comment: Thanks I am checking currently

Comment: Short question while I am checking if results are properly returned: why did you use concat I am trying to understand? You could not use T3.ID1 which is T2 ID but you have to concatanate T1 ID and T2 ID but not sure why? Thanks

Comment: as we are going to group only by Groupinfo, we need the status_1 to be vendor for a distinct values of t2id of t1ids belonging to group1. so the concatenation acts as a key to get only distinct values of combination id1 and id2

Comment: I checked and now I do not have multiple results for other columns (first issue is resolved) but still for the column VENDOR I am getting multiple results if that record ID had been multiple times in T2 table.  So it seems this CONCAT with those two columns did not help us. Do you have any other idea how we can resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Let me get this straight....You have t2 IDs 2 and 3 have status as vendor just for example and these IDs have t1id 1 so for vendor you want to count this as 1 or 2?

Comment: I want to count this as 1.  It seems if I put   count (distinct(case when t3.status_1 ="VENDOR" then t3.id end)) as Vendor   it works. Can you double check but it seems we found solution :)

Comment: Then no need of the concat just t3.id is enough

Comment: Thank you really for all your efforts and for time spend to resolve this issue it was really hard :) I marked this as an answer.  Quick question which I asked before: in order to filter T1 table additionally I just need to put  WHERE clause after the on t1.id=t2.t1id statement correct?

Comment: Don't put where just add the condition by adding an and

Comment: why I should not add WHERE? Is there some difference? Thanks

Comment: Where is used to state conditions...Here already on is doing the same job....So no need of specifying where again

Comment: Thanks it seems then it has the same purpose

Comment: yeah it depends on the way you mention join or just use a comma to specify tables